# Virtual assignment operator overloading- how the correct overloaded function is chosen?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, overloading, assignment-operator

The following code (from C++ FAQs 24.11) is implementing virtual assignment operator overloading and overriding:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
>
> class B{
> public:
>     virtual ~B() throw();
>     virtual B& operator= (const B& b) throw();
> };
>
> B::~B() throw(){}
>
> B& B::operator= (const B& b) throw()
> { cout << "B::operator=(const B&)\n"; return *this; }
>
>
> class D : public B{
> public:
>     virtual D& operator= (const B& b) throw();
>     D& operator= (const D& d) throw();
> };
>
> D& D::operator= (const B& b) throw()
> {cout << "D::operator= (const B&)\n"; return *this;}
>
> D& D::operator= (const D& d) throw()
> {cout << "D::operator= (const D&)\n"; return *this;}
>
>
> void sample(D& d, B& b, D& d2, B& b2){
>     cout << "d = d2:   "; d = d2;
>     cout << "d = b2:   "; d = b2;
>     cout << "b = b2:   "; b = b2;
>     cout << "b = d2:   "; b = d2;
> }
>
>
> int main()
> {
>     D d, b, d2, b2;
>     sample(d,b,d2,b2);
> }
> ```

and it says the output is:

- d = d2:     D::operator=(const D&)
- d = b2:     D::operator=(const B&)
- b = b2:     D::operator=(const B&)
- b = d2:     D::operator=(const B&)

It says:

> "Because the compiler resolves which override to call based on the
>   static type of the parameters, the first assignment is the only one
>   that calls the assignment operator that takes a D; all the others end
>   up calling the assignment operator that takes a B."

and

> "The last two calls resolve to the override (D::operator= (const B&))
>   because the actual class of b in sample() is D. If b had actually been
>   a B, the last two calls would have resolve to (B::operator= (const
>   B&))"

I'm a bit confused, the first paragraph says the compiler looks at the parameter static type to determine which (overloaded?) function call is used, so why does the last case call the operator for the B parameter type, when the argument passed, d2, is declared as type `D& d2` in sample()?

**EDIT Referring to the answer below, I do not see how the request for B::=(D) can result in D::=(B). What if there was another subclass, E? Why would D::=(B) get called and not E::=(B)? Are we saying if B does not have a function '=' for parameter (D) then the run-time starts looking at whether any derived objects contain such a signature?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overload resolution is done using the static types. Once the overload is picked, the dynamic type is used to determine which overridden version of the function is used. Let me explain each result:

```
//Every object is a D object, so in
//each case, we expect the virtual calls
//to dispatch to the D version.

//lhs: D, rhs: D, so we expect
//D::operator=(D const&)
cout << "d = d2:   "; d = d2;

//lhs: D, rhs: B, so we expect
//D::operator=(B const&)
cout << "d = b2:   "; d = b2;

//lhs: B, rhs: B, so we expect
//B::operator=(B const&).
//This is virtual, and has been overridden
//in D, so the D version gets called.
cout << "b = b2:   "; b = b2;

//lhs: B, rhs: D, so we expect
//B::operator(D const&).
//This does not exist, so the closest match is used:
//B::operator(B const&). (This is a legal match, 
//because D is a subclass of B).
//This is virtual, and has been overridden
//in D, so the D version gets called.
cout << "b = d2:   "; b = d2;
```

Comment: Thanks- a question though. In #3 I understand a virtual overridden form has been provided in the derived, but why does this suddenly make the version in the base class b obsolete? I could understand if the object types were D, but they are the base class B? Surely a B object would use the assignment operator in B? I know about overriding, but I didnt think in this case the overridden version in D would get called?

Comment: Further to my point above- if you had another derived class, call it E, which over-rides the operator= (just like D does)....  E::operator(const B&), how would B know whether to call the D version or the E version?

Comment: @user997112: In every case, the dynamic type of the object is `D` (**not** `B`) -- you constructed `D` objects in main, and passed them in to the function by reference, so the dynamic type was not changed. You have marked the functions as `virtual`, and `virtual` means "dispatch based on the dynamic type of the object the function is being invoked on". If you had passed `E` objects in as the `b` and `b2` arguments, then the `E` versions would be called.