# How Overloading and Overriding work together?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading, overriding, dynamic-binding

I understand the basics of overloading and overriding- but something is confusing me. I will try to explain using a simple example:

- Class B has a function  X(B& b)
- Class D inherits from Class B.
- Class D overrides X with X(B& b) and also overloads it with X(D& d).

I then have the following code:

```
void test(D& d1, B& b1, D& d2, B& b2){
    d1.X(d2);
    d1.X(b2);
    b1.X(d2);
    b1.X(b2);
}

int main(){
    D d1, d2, d3, d4;
    test(d1, d2, d3, d4);
}
```

I am very unsure how the third and four lines of `test()` would determine which implementations of X() to call and what the general mechanisms are which are happening.

Comment: Polymorphism only happens with pointers and references; passing by value slices the `D`s into `B`s. Also even if you fix that, the overload `D::X(D)` will not be visible when you call `X` through a `B&`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I fixed my post to include the references. Apparently b1.X(b2) will call D.X(B& b)..... this is what I do not understand...

Comment: `B` doesn't have a function `X(D)`, only `D` does. Also the types of arguments to functions (virtual or static, either) are taken statically, not dynamically.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I know what you are saying- but that is the answer. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179854/virtual-assignment-operator-overloading-how-the-correct-overloaded-function-is

Comment: What did you want me to see?

Comment: The fourth line in test()- b1.X(b2) ends up calling D.X(B&)- this is what I cannot understand. In your second comment it seemed like you were disagreeing?

Comment: No, I was agreeing and explaining why. Like the question you linked to said, the overload is determined at compile time, and the version of the overload is determined at runtime for virtual functions. Since `B` doesn't have `X(D)` you can't call it through a `B&` even if that `B&` refers to a `D` underneath.

Comment: Sorry for this- but I don't understand this: b1.X(b2) is, to the compiler, an object of type B wishing to invoke X(B&)? So in class B there is a virtual function X(B&). So why doesn't it just call this? Why does it then look at what the derived class D has? Surely it cannot just pick a derived function because it was declared virtual? If there was a second derived class how would it know which derived class it should pick, when type B is the argument?

Comment: That's what virtual is: it lets the implementation of an overload be selected at runtime. The overload itself is determined at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps involved: overload selection (`X(B&)` vs. `X(D&)`) and, once that is done, finding the right implementation of the selected function. The former happens at compile time and depends on the *static types* of the object *and* its arguments, the latter happens at run-time and depends on the *dynamic type* of the object (note it does *not* depend on the dynamic type of the arguments).

The four objects are declared as follows: `d1` and `d2` are `D&`, so their *static type* is `D&`, and `b1` and `b2` are declared as `B&`, so their static type is `B&`. The static type is what you've declared in the code.

But the *dynamic type* for all four is `D`, because all four references *actually* refer to objects that you've created as `D`-objects in `main()`.

Therefore, first step, overload selection: In the case of `b1.X(b2)` and `b1.X(d2)`, there is only one possible overload, `X(B&)`, because the static type is `B&`, and the class definition for `B` has only this one function. But in the case of `d1.X(b2)` and `d1.X(d2)`, the overload selection is based on the class definition of `D`, because the static type is `D&`. So two overloads are considered: `X(B&)` and `X(D&)`. When the argument is `b2`, the former overload is chosen, and when the argument is `d2`, the latter overload is chosen – all based on the static (=declared) types of object and arguments.

Second step, chosing the right implementation of the selected overload. This happens at run-time and depends on the dynamic type of the object (not the arguments). So in the case of `b1.X(b2)`, because the dynamic type of `b1` is `D`, it will end up calling `D::X(B&)`. Same for `b1.X(d2)`: The overload selected in the previous step was `X(B&)`, but the implementation chosen is `D::X(B&)`. (`D::X(D&)` is no candidate at this point, because that would be a different overload, and the overload has been chosen based on the static type already). In the case of `d1.X(b2)` and `d1.X(d2)`, the selected functions are the same as in the first step, `D::X(B&)` and `D::X(D&)`, because the dynamic type of the object is the same as the static type.

Comment: Excellent answer- You really explained this well!

Comment: So to clarify, we don't bother looking at the second stage for the first two assignments because the static type and dynamic type of the invoking objects (D) match. In other words, the first stage determines which of the static-type overloads is called and the second stage determines (if the dynamic type doesnt match the static type) from which class in the inheritance hierarchy do we invoke this chosen overloaded function.

Comment: Yes, that's right -- or actually, the second step does take place, but it doesn't change anything because, as you say, the dynamic type is the same as the static type.

Answer (score 2):

You declare a virtual function `X` in `B(B::X)`, and override the `X` in the derived class `D(D::X)`. If the parameter lists of `B::X` and `D::X` are different, `B::X` and `D::X` are considered different, `D::X` does not override `B::X`, and `D::X` is not virtual (unless you have declared it with the virtual keyword). Instead, `D::X` hides `B::X`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct B {
   virtual void X() { cout << "Class B" << endl; }
};

struct D: B {
   void X(int) { cout << "Class D" << endl; }
};

int main() {
   D d;
   B* pb = &d;
//   d.X();
   pb->X();
}
```

You cannot even call `d.X()`, it is hidden by `D::X(int)`. But `pb->X()` is fine.

So in your case:

```
struct B {
   virtual void X(B& b) { cout << "Class B" << endl; }
};

struct D: B {
   void X(B& b) { cout << "Class D" << endl; }
   void X(D& d) { cout << "Class D" << endl; }
};
```

The `D::X` will hide the `B::X`. So `d1.X(d2)` and `d1.X(b2)` in `test()` have nothing to do with `B::X`. And `b1.X(d2)`, and `b1.X(b2)` in `test()` will call `D::X`. Although the `B::X` is invisible in D, but `D::X(B&)` is virtual, regardless of  whether or not you declare `D::X(B&)` with the virtual keyword. The compiler knows it is a virtual function, so `D::X(B&)` gets called.

EDIT: More explaination on b1.X(b2), B::X is a virtual function, and D::X override it, so definitely it will call D::X by dynamic binding. And overloading is determined in compilation time, so it won't call D::X(D&).

Comment: The last 'why not' looks like a question? @jogojapan

Comment: I think he asked a question to me, saying "you get what I mean?"

Comment: @moderator: This was flagged as "not an answer" due to a misunderstanding. **Please ignore the flag.**